# AutoMapper with a complex EF Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, automapper-6

I have a basic table with a few  FK references. So when I retrieve an entity for an update operation; that entity contains `ICollections`of related entites. I also have a main ViewModel inside which each entity is a sub viewModel. My aim is to use Automapper like:

```
mapper.Map(MainViewmodel obj,MainEntity obj);
```

For this I have a MappingConfiguration like:

```
 CreateMap<MainViewModel, MainEntity>();
 CreateMap<subViewModel1, subEntity1>();
 CreateMap<subViewModel2, subEntity2>();
```

This gives me an Unmapped properties exception because the `ICollections` are not getting mapped. Could anyone please guide me on the best way to deal with this kind of situation?

thanks.

Comment: hi..there is a correction. It does not throw a exception(that was my mistake in passing argument).. at the same time, it does not map as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you has classes like this:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    ICollection<SubViewModel1> SubViewModels { get;set; }
}

class SubViewModel1
{
}
```

and

```
class MainEntity
{
    ICollection<SubEntity1> SubEntities { get;set; }
}

class SubEntity1
{    
}
```

Then you should create rules for each class, and collection of such classes automaper map automatically.

```
CreateMap<MainViewModel, MainEntity>();
CreateMap<SubViewModel1, SubEntity1>();
```

**Addditions 1:**

1. Try this method: `var mappedMainEntity = rmapper.Map<MainEntity>(MainViewmodel obj);`
2. If you map `MainEntity` to `MainViewModel` you need add .ReverseMap() to map rule, like this:

   CreateMap().ReverseMap();
   CreateMap().ReverseMap();

**Additions 2:**

1. AutoMapper mapping public Properties only
2. If the mapping Properties have different names, you need to use explicitly indicating how to map these Properties. Using `ForMember` method and `MapFrom` option. [Example](http://gist.github.com/Asc0tt/409473b2716c93bf39026694e899592a)

Comment: hi @Anton Gorbunov in MainViewModel.. the subViewModel is not declared as an `ICollection` . I have used `List<subViewModel>`

Comment: Hi @Shwrk. Typically, for the automapper, the collection type does not matter. Please, see and try additions in answer

Comment: hmm.. @Anton Gorbunov it didn't work mate, the `mappedMainEntity` turned out empty

Comment: good news :) It works when I specify `ForMember` property for each `ICollection`..  values are mostly null though which I think is some naming issue.. will check it out. thanks for your help

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried to write the code for an example and realized that I forgot to mention two important features. =))
1. AutoMapper mapping public Properties only
2. If the Properties have different names, you need to use explicitly indicating how to create these Properties using ForMember method and MapFrom option

Comment: Example =) https://gist.github.com/Asc0tt/409473b2716c93bf39026694e899592a

Comment: np mate :) I have 1 more issue.. In the main Entity.. I have some properties in addition to `ICollections`.  These properties are mapped in a subViewModel from View. So when I write `CreateMap<MainViewModel, MainEntity>()`, these fields don't get mapped to entity because they inside of a subViewModel. So I am currently writing `ForMember` for each such field(around 20). Is there a better way to do it?